# Unable to set sheet zoom% to 120 using apache POI

Tags: apache-poi

How can I set sheet zoom% to 120 using Apache POI ?

I tried with `sheet.setZoom(5,4)` but its outputs to 125% zoom.
Also this method accepts only integers.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [API docs for the Sheet interface](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html) in Apache POI state:

> setZoom(int scale) - Window zoom magnification for current view
>   representing percent values.

and

> setZoom(int numerator, int denominator) 
>   Deprecated.
>   2015-11-23 (circa POI 3.14beta1). Use setZoom(int) instead.

So try:

```
sheet.setZoom(120);
```

Or to use the deprecated method on an older version of the API:

```
sheet.setZoom(12, 10);
```

Note, 5/4=1.25 which is the reason you get zoomed to 125%

Comment: Correct, but 12/10 = 6/5.

Comment: Thanks Finbarr & Axel. That worked. I am using 3.6 version of apache POI so i would go with setZoom(int numerator, int denominator). :)